# Identifying a thread as a "Remote thread"

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I'm working on a process which analizes what another process does.
It checks the CPU, memory usage, threads creating and dying, etc.
Unfortunately I have an antivirus installed on my computer which creates a remote thread in my examined process. This remote thread is not really a part of the process so I'd like to ignore this thread completley while examining the process.

Is there a way (in C++) which allows us to identify a thread as a "remote thread"?

Comment: Uninstall the virus. (Yes, I know you said antivirus, but IMO, one that installs a thread in every process is itself a virus).

Comment: Ok, but still... suppose my client really loves his virus and doesn't want to uninstall. Can't I somehow detect if a thread is a remote thread?

Comment: *suppose my client really loves his virus* - LOL

Comment: If you checks the CPU, memory usage etc you can`t ignore this thread or others.

Comment: @sergmat: yes, but I'm checking other things too and for that I want to ignore this thread. Also I might want to display data per thread and I don't want to display the remote thread's data.

Comment: I think about the only way to detect that a thread was remote would be to hook into the process of its starting up (e.g., using MS Detours) so you could see the initial call to `CreateRemoteThread` happening. There *may* be another way, but that's the only one that's obvious to me right off.

Comment: But then I'll have to hook into the injecting process, won't I? because it's the one which calls "CreateRemoteThread".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are willing to go kernel mode [PsSetCreateThreadNotifyRoutine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff559954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be of interest to you. According to [Uninformed](http://uninformed.org/index.cgi?v=8&a=2&p=18) it is called in the context of the process **'that is creating or terminating the thread'**. I have also seen this suggested [elsewhere](http://www.osronline.com/showThread.CFM?link=123263).

I got round to testing this, it works fine. *You should note that you will see a number of false positives as Windows (unsurprisingly) does some injection itself.* <EDIT> **This is actually caused because on process creation as the first thread is created it will be done in the context of the parent process**. Simply eliminate first thread creation and this gives a pretty good indication. </EDIT>

The main draw back (other than having to write a driver) would be you need to see the creation happen, so your process needs to start first.

Alternatively, as mentioned, heuristics involving stack traces, loaded modules and all that good stuff come into play.

Answer (score 8):

Internally there is no distinction between threads created with `CreateThread` and threads created with `CreateRemoteThread`. (Interally, `CreateThread` basically calls `CreateRemoteThread` and passes `GetCurrentProcess()` as the target process.) If you want to distinguish the threads, you will have to use heuristics.